# python3-protobuf yocto receipe, getting compiler error

Tags: python, build, protocol-buffers, yocto, recipe

I have been trying to compile python3-protobuf package from Yocto dunfell release, but I am getting compiler error.

I am below recipe from Yocto without any change:

**python3-protobuf_3.11.3.bb**

```
inherit setuptools3
require python-protobuf.inc
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

DEPENDS += "protobuf"
DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS += "--cpp_implementation"
DISTUTILS_INSTALL_ARGS += "--cpp_implementation"

do_compile_prepend_class-native () {
    export KOKORO_BUILD_NUMBER="1"
}
```

I am getting below error

```
aarch64-oe-linux-gcc -march=armv8-a+crc -fstack-protector-strong -pie -fPIE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/admin/build/distro-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-protobuf/3.11.3-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -O2 -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -ftree-vectorize -finline-functions -finline-limit=64 -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -Wno-error=unused-result -O2 -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -ftree-vectorize -finline-functions -finline-limit=64 -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -Wno-error=unused-result -O2 -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -ftree-vectorize -finline-functions -finline-limit=64 -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -Wno-error=unused-result -fPIC -I. -I../src -I/home/admin/build/distro-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-protobuf/3.11.3-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/python3.8 -c google/protobuf/pyext/message.cc -o /home/admin/build/distro-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-protobuf/3.11.3-r0/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/google/protobuf/pyext/message.o -Wno-write-strings -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-variable -std=c++11
google/protobuf/pyext/message.cc:70:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/stubs/map_util.h: No such file or directory
   70 | #include <google/protobuf/stubs/map_util.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'aarch64-oe-linux-gcc' failed with exit status 1
ERROR: 'python3 setup.py build  --cpp_implementation' execution failed.
WARNING: /home/admin/build/distro-debug/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/python3-protobuf/3.11.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.15287:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
```

If I remove below from recipe

```
DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS += "--cpp_implementation"
DISTUTILS_INSTALL_ARGS += "--cpp_implementation"
```

from the recipe, then I do not get any error.

Thanks

Comment: do you have aarch64-oe-linux-gcc installed?

Comment: a wrong version of probobuf?

Comment: @John b Yes.. aarch64-oe-linux-gcc installed